# Laravel route redirect to 404 with nginx

Tags: laravel, nginx

I have a laravel app on my VM and i setup the server with nginx, but everytime i call the route, it's not working and redirect to 404 not found

this is my nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;

    server_name _;

    location / {
                #deny all;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

    location /crm-api {
        root /var/www/crm-api/public; #
        rewrite ^/crm-api/(.*)$ /$1 break; #

        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }


    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        set $newurl $request_uri; #
                if ($newurl ~ ^/crm-api(.*)$) { #
                        set $newurl $1; #
                        root /var/www/crm-api/public; #
                } #
        try_files $uri=404 /index.php=404;
        #fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

        fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $newurl; #
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params; 
    }
}
```

i created /crm-api because i want to run multiple app on my vm, i have tried a couple solution but it's still not working.

Comment: The statement `try_files $uri=404 /index.php=404;` does not look right. What is it supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code block instead of your location code block

```
location / {
    # Redirect everything that isn't a real file to index.php
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score -2):

this is my config an it works

```
location / {
 # First attempt to serve request as file, then
 # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

Comment: This answer does not add anything from the answer from 2019. If it works for you too, just upvote the original answer.